# Remove an item from map

Tags: java

I create a map in Java such as `private Map<Integer, List<entity>> m`, how can I remove an item stay in List?

I run loop in Map to `m.get(key).size()` and remove when the condition is true:
 `if (m.get(key).get(i).getID() = xxx);` removed clause `m.get(key).remove(i).`

Comment: I run loop in Map to m.get(key).size() and remove when the condition is true: if (m.get(key).get(i).getID() = xxx); removed clause m.get(key).remove(i). What's wrong here?

Comment: @Phúc It seems feasible to me. Does it throw exception or what? Also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/java-efficient-equivalent-to-removing-while-iterating-a-collection) question for safe removing from list.

Comment: I have two table in database with 1-n relationship, table have relationship 1 i fill into combobox. And it do filter data of datatable which was loaded from the List<entity>, the table have relationship n. I did action but the datatable did not update although i used update="@this" or update "@form", and i do same for process attribute in <p:commandButton>.

Comment: The item in List<entity> was removed successfully but it dose not refresh datatable. Pls someone help me!

Answer (score 0):

I'd go over the map entries and use the [`removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) method to remove the relevant elements from each list:

```
m.values().forEeach(v -> v.removeIf(i -> i.getId() == 123));
// Just an example, of course ------------------------^
```